# How to add headers in express-redis-cache package

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis, http-headers

I am using [express-redis-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-redis-cache)([Github](https://github.com/rv-kip/express-redis-cache)). I am adding headers

```
router.get(
  '/:id([a-f0-9]{24})',
  (req, res, next) => {
    // set cache name
    res.express_redis_cache_name = 'task-' + req.params.id;
    next();
  },
  cache.route({
    expire: {
      200: 3600,
      xxx: 0
    }
  }),
  taskMiddlewares.findByIdWithUser,
  (req, res) => {
    res
      .set({
        'Cache-Control': 'private, must-revalidate',
        'Last-Modified': req.task.updatedAt.toUTCString()
      })
      .json(taskTransformer(req.task));
  }
);
```

But when get response from cache it doesn't include the `Cache-Control` & `Last-Modified` headers.

> How to include those headers from cache response